# How to parse all MySQL variables from a table to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I want to create a MySQL table to keep all my variables in, so I can edit them when needed from one place.

This is what I need to accomplish.

Right now the way I parse variables to my JQuery script is this.

```
    <input type='button' value='Ein / Aus' class='taster' output='#output' write-datatyp='DB' write-db='100' write-byte='0' write-bit='0' bit-value='1' read-datatyp='A' read-db='0' read-byte='2' read-bit='0' />      

    <script>
    $(document).on('click', 'input.taster', function() {

        //Output
        var out = $(this).attr('output');

        //Write
        var wdatatyp = $(this).attr('write-datatyp');
        var wdb = $(this).attr('write-db');
        var wbyte = $(this).attr('write-byte');
        var wbit = $(this).attr('write-bit');           
        var bitval = $(this).attr('bit-value'); 

        //Read          
        var rdatatyp = $(this).attr('read-datatyp');
        var rdb = $(this).attr('read-db');
        var rbyte = $(this).attr('read-byte');
        var rbit = $(this).attr('read-bit');            

        $(document).load('plc.php?function=write-bit', {'datatyp':wdatatyp, 'db':wdb, 'byte':wbyte, 'bit':wbit, 'bit-value':bitval});   

        function read() {               
            $(out).load('plc.php?function=read-bit', {'datatyp':rdatatyp, 'db':rdb, 'byte':rbyte, 'bit':rbit});                 
        }
        setTimeout(read, 100);          
        $(this).attr('bit-value', bitval^1);    // xor bit to toggle value          
    });
    </script>
```

I want to be able to call an entire table in the input tag and have it assign the correct variables to the JQuery script.

Something like...

```
    <input type='button' value='Ein / Aus' class='taster' table='test' />
```

Then it should parse all variables from the table 'test' to the JQuery

This is the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
      `wdatatyp` text NOT NULL,
      `wdb` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `wbyte` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `wbit` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `bitval` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `rdatatyp` text NOT NULL,
      `rdb` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `rbyte` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `rbit` int(11) NOT NULL
    )
```

How would I go about doing this is a somewhat simple way?

Thanks!

Comment: use a class model in php to map table data; then in the server request of ajax call return a json object of your model (json_encode($myclassmodel)) and parse it in jquery in your front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt this code to your need:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Was it when you ran it?

Comment: Well that is what I used when I ran it, it didn't output anything

Comment: If it doesn't output anything the table is empty.